Error Login Auth0 en Flutter
Estoy desarrollando una app mobile en Flutter e integrando el Login de Auth0.
Tengo un problema en la mayoría de los dispositivos que cuando abro la aplicación, me salta un error que no estoy pudiendo solucionar de raíz, y para poder avanzar, hago una nueva llamada al método de Login y ahi se soluciona.
NO puedo replicar esto en los emuladores de iOS ni Android! Me funciona todo bien en desarrollo, es algo que pasa cuando instalo en los dispositivos desde el store.
Es decir, en el primer llamado al login aparece el error, si reintento ese llamado, funciona bien.
El error en iOS es:

error domain com apple authenticationservices
webauthetnticacionsession code=3 the uiwindowscene for the returned
window was not in the foreground active state

y en Android:

A change on the Lock Screen security settings have deemed the
encryption keys invalid and have been recreated. Please try saving the
credentials again

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      loadData();
    });
  }

Future<void> loadData() async {
    try {
      await dotenv.load();
      final credentials = await ref.read(loginProvider.future);
      credentials.fold((failure) {
        errorCount++;
        if (errorCount <= 3) {
          showAuthExpiredSessionAlert(context: context, fn: loadData);
        } else {
          showAuthErrorAlert(context: context, error: failure, fn: loadData);
        }
        return;
      }, (credential) {
        //Redirect home
        context.go('/home');
        return;
      });
    } catch (e, stackTrace) {
      if (mounted) {
        errorCount++;
        if (errorCount <= 3) {
          showAuthExpiredSessionAlert(context: context, fn: loadData);
        } else {
          showAuthErrorAlert(
              context: context,
              error: Failure(e.toString()),
              stackTrace: stackTrace,
              fn: loadData);
        }
      }
    }
  }

Si pueden ver, en el "catch" muestro un cartel de error pero con el botón de reintento, y ahí funciona el login correctamente en el 100% de los casos.
No encontré nada al respecto de por qué se genera esto. Cualquier información será bien recibida.
